# unable to install windows and remove manjaro

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have Manjaro installed on my pc and now i want to remove it and install windows 7. made a bootable usb and tried installing. but getting many errors. i tried both GPT and MBR partition scheme. in boot options tried both Legacy and UEFI with secure boot on and off.

the error i get is " A required CD/DVD drive device driver is missing. If you have a drive floppy disk, CD, DVD or USB flash drive, please insert it now."\

NOte: if the windows installation media is in the CD/DVD drive, you can safely remove it for this step.

that bootable usb works effectively on existing windows pc.

I tried both front and back usb ports.

i dont know any linux. kindly explain in detail please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ports use USB 3.x, then Windows 7 cannot use them, as it lacks USB 3.x
drivers.

Go into the BIOS, into a section that might have a name like
"System configuration".
Select "USB 3.0 Configuration in Pre-OS" or similar, and change it from "Enabled"
to "Auto". This allows the USB ports to function as USB 2.0 during boot,
but once the OS starts they will be switched to USB 3.0.
You can set this back to "Enabled" after you have installed the OS.
Do not forget to hit "Save and exit" to finish the BIOS setup.

If you have USB 2.0 ports, using them will also solve the problem
without changing the BIOS settings.

If your USB hardware is the "Intel® USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller",
the driver may be downloaded
[from here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/22824/Intel-USB-3-0-eXtensible-Host-Controller-Driver-for-Intel-8-9-100-Series-and-Intel-C220-C610-Chipset-Family?product=65855),
for installation after Windows 7 is completely installed.

Comment: Note: I really recommend using Windows 10, if possible.

Comment: windows 10 caused lots of troubles earlier so, i am opting for windows 7. so, can you please explain a little about extensible host controller ? and if i go for windows 10 wont i have this problem ? i have a windows 7 dvd as well. al usb ports is USB 3.0 i guess . also, i did not get any option to change usb to auto / enable  in bios

Comment: Windows 10 latest version has the USB 3.x driver. Check if the ports have the SS symbol for USB 3.x (if you aren't sure).